# Python recursive limit and how to keep monitoring something

Tags: python, tkinter, recursion

I am working on a python tkinter program that monitoring computer temperature, and I want it to update the temperature value after a fixed time.
the following function is what I used to do that:

```
    def update():
        get_temp()#the function that get the computer temperature value, like cpu temperature.
        ...
    def upd():
        update()
        time.sleep(0.3)
        upd()#recursive call function.

    upd()
```

but this way will hit the recursive limit, so the program will stops after a period of time.
I want it to keep updating the value, what should I do?
I don't know if I change it to `after()` it will be better or not.
but if I use `after()`, the tkinter window will freeze a while, so I don't want to use it.
Thank you.

Comment: Use a loop instead of recursion!

Comment: Don't recurse, use a loop.  And I don't know how tkinter works, but most GUI frameworks have a timer function that will send a message after the timer expires so you don't have to block your main event loop while waiting for it.

Comment: tkinter's after can solve it, but it will lag when I move the window...or there is something else to do a loop?

Comment: I think I really solve the problem,it not the problem of python,and I finally understand why others said I need loop. I'll write down my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is inadequate in this use-case, use a loop instead.

Tkinter in particular has got a **method** which allows you to execute a **function** in an interval without disrupting the GUI's **event loop**.

Quick example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
INTERVAL = 1000 # in milliseconds

def get_temp()
   # ...
   root.after(INTERVAL, get_temp) 

get_temp()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, It worked. But if I use it, it will lag when I move the window(so I call it "freezed") and I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: @Corporation try the updated answer

Comment: It still happened when I change it to get_temp(), I am also tried use it in thread, but the same situation.

Comment: @Corporation Please provide the rest of your code then, otherwise we can't do much for you

Comment: Actually, just a simple tkinter window,and a function with after and to do something like print can cause the freeze.

Comment: I solved it, I changed my python version to 3.8 and it solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: ok,I think I really solve the problem,it not the problem of python,and I finally understand why others said I need loop. I'll write down my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It needs loop.
It should be:

```
def update():
    get_temp()#the function that get the computer temperature value, like cpu temperature.
    ...

def upd():
    while True:#needs a while true here and don't call upd() in this function.
        update()
        time.sleep(0.3)

upd()#this upd() is outside the function upd(),it used to start the function.
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me.